# Is it OK to include a personal (non-science related) statement in the final slide of a presentation

Tags: presentation

Is it OK to include a personal note telling intention of hard-work on the topic,

> e.g. I am looking forward to work on this problem

in the Conclusion slide of a presentation related to possible research topic in the future?

I believe the Conclusion slide is used to collect the scientific conclusions about the work in the end of the presentation as a takeaway message, how would such a statement stand in the end?

Comment: Who is the audience?  Why would this statement matter to them?

Comment: Why not just say it?

Comment: In Computer Science, that would be perfectly fine.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist not sure if it would matter to them. The audice is, among others, the supervisors etc.

Comment: @DaveClarke written statement has stronger impression

Comment: If it does not matter to the audience, leave it out.

Comment: Text on the slides should be used sparingly and wisely. This is certainly not one of the core ideas you want to convey. Leave it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that writing on the presentation that you'll be looking forward to doing something is somewhat out of place.

In addition, it appears that you may be confusing two separate definitions of `conclusion`.

The first is the scientific conclusion, which you have defined. This is, as you've described, the takeaway message from scientific research, i.e.

> This research shows us that potatoes are actually tasty.

The second is a presentation's conclusion. This can be the scientific conclusion in a presentation about an actual study. However, you're referring to a proposal, which has no conclusion, or perhaps to a slide mentioning future possible research topics.

In this case, your conclusion should be a summary of what you've covered during your presentation, preferably onto one slide, i.e.

> Conclusion 
>    - This research will establish whether or not potatoes are tasty
>    - Important to humanity as it helps determine whether or not further investment into discovery of potato recipes are practical
>    - Funding this project will be cheap as potatoes are grown a lot already

Then, when you present your situation, you can mention `I look forward to performing this research with your support.` and it flows cleanly.

If I've interpreted anything incorrectly regarding your situation, OP, let me know.

Comment: everything is straight to the point

Answer (score 2):

While it's generally OK to add a personal thought, it's important to be careful with what sort message you add at the end of a talk.  What do you want the audience to get from this extra message, and will it conflict with the rest of the talk?

Some examples I've seen that worked:

- A mention of how the science links to some sort of outreach or broader impact goals that personally motivate you.
- A cute / funny vaguely related image that lets you end on a light note, e.g., the speaker's child interacting with a robot at the end of a robotics talk.

Some examples I've seen that didn't work:

- A declaration that all of this work was in service of the higher glory of Christ (caused a rather awkward silence in the highly diverse and international audience)
- Not actually stopping, but just rambling about unrelated things until the session chair actually physically shut off the projector.

Something bland like, "I'm looking forward to working on this project" is so normal and unexceptional that the audience may not even notice that you said it.